# Plot simple array in python - different size of input arrays

Tags: arrays, plot, size

I'm a new Python user (this is my first post at stackoverflow) and have some problems understanding the different types of variables in python. Previously I have mostly used Matlab for the tasks I want to do but there are some differences in Python, I think.

I do some matrix operations, resulting in array (list?) "ahs", then the three first elements of "ahs" are stored in scalar variables "a, b, c" (scalar is what I call them, may not be correct.., their content is just different numbers, 2, 3e6, -10 etc).

Then I want to plot a quadratic curve, but the two arrays (?..) "xh" (from linspace) and "sh" (from quadratic expression) have different size (or type?) and can't be plotted. When examined individual elements of "sh" seems to be correct and my guess is that the plot problem refers to size issues.

```
  a=ahs[0]
  b=ahs[1]
  c=ahs[2]             
  xh=np.linspace(0,x3,num=100)
  sh=a*xh**2+b*xh+c 
  print(np.shape(xh))
  print(np.shape(sh))
```

The output I get:

```
(100,)
(1, 100)
raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension")
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension
```

This is most likely very simple to fix, but I just can't figure it out how to get variable "sh" to be of shape (100,).

Thanks,
Erik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward solution is to just flatten `sh`:

```
sh = sh.ravel()
```

This takes no additional memory since it is just a `view` of the original array.

You can also just get the first index of `sh`, which will reduce the dimensionality:

```
sh = sh[0]
```

You can also use `np.squeeze` to eliminate length-1 dimensions, although that is more verbose in this case (it is safer, though, if you aren't sure the dimensions have a length of 1):

```
sh = np.squeeze(sh)
```

However, this result should not happen if `a`, `b`, and `c` are indeed scalars (that is the correct term).  So you should check the shape of each one (if it has a shape), because I think you will find one or more of them is not actually a scalar.

By the way, you don't have to index like that.  This is much simpler:

```
a, b, c = ahs[:3]
```

Or  if you are sure that ahs only has three elements:

```
a, b, c = ahs
```

Also, if you are dealing with numpy arrays, it is generally considered better to use `arr.shape`, rather than `np.shape(arr)`.  `np.shape(arr)`, however, is safer if you don't know whether `arr` is a numpy array or not.

Comment: You were right about the scalar variables a,b,c; they were indeed [1x1]-matrices (which I should have found out myself..)  and when I fixed that the different size problem vanish. Also very useful for  me with the different functions/methods you described, it's a problem when you are new to a language and know what you want to do but don't know all possible built-in functions that can be used.